# How to build update site project for multiple platforms in a single build?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, build-process, eclipse-pde

I am having a set of eclipse plug-ins developed for both Linux and Windows environment. It includes platform dependent fragment plug-ins for Linux and Windows built using an update site project. Since they are only plugins I don't build using eclipse product definition. 
Currently I have to build the update site separately for Linux and Windows. But I want to build for both Linux and Windows at the same time either in Linux or Windows. Is there any solution for this?